# React native Modal not showing up unless I make a change and save my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a goods-in app for a handheld device built in react native. Whenever a product is scanned using the barcode scanner I want to set it as selected and then have that products details pop up in a modal for the user. The problem I'm having is the modal is not popping up but the existing details are disappearing and if I make a change to the Modals props and then save it the page reloads and the Modal appears.

Another thing that I find strange is if I remove the `<Modal>` and just have it switch to a `<View>` It works no problem.

```
const OrderLineItem = ({item, finishEditingInQty}) => {

const {selected} = item

if(selected){
    console.log("Item selected")
    return (
        <Modal
            style={styles.centeredView}
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={true}
        >
            <View style={styles.modalLineItemContainer}>
                <View style={styles.modalLineItem}>
                    <Text>SELECTED</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.modalLineItem}>
                    <Text>{item.sageStockInfo.Barcode}</Text>
                </View>
                <Pressable
                    onPress={() => {
                        finishEditingInQty(item.LineID)
                    }}
                    style={({ pressed }) => [
                        {
                            backgroundColor: pressed
                            ? 'rgb(210, 230, 255)'
                            : 'white'
                        },
                        styles.orderListItem
                ]}>
                    <Text>Done</Text>
                </Pressable>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    )
} else {
    return (
        <View style={styles.lineItemContainer}>
            <View style={styles.lineItem}>
                <Text style={styles.lineItemText}>{item.ProductCode} - {item.ProductDescription}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.lineItem}>
                <Text style={styles.lineItemText}>Outstanding: {item.Quantity}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.lineItemText}>In Qty: {item.inQty}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.lineItem}>
                <Text style={styles.lineItemText}>Warehouse: {item.Warehouse}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.lineItem}>
                <Text style={styles.lineItemText}>{item.sageStockInfo.Barcode}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Visible in Modal has `boolean` type. In your code `visible={selected}`? What is 'selected'?

Comment: Selected is coming from a field on item, I have hardcoding this too true and it still does not render. The console log for "Item Selected" does appear though.

Comment: if selected is 'false' it should show the modal but the 'visible' property of the modal will be false (since 'selected===false')

Comment: Yeah the selected was true I left the exclamation in by mistake when I posted it, edited now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Modal in a very strange way. When I want a modal, in code very similar to this, I do the following.

```
<View>
  <Modal
    visible={selected}
    ....
  >
    ...Modal content
  </Modal>
  ...other content displayed while modal is not up
</View>
```

If the modal is visible, it covers everything else - its a modal and that's what it should do. No need to have logic determining which view to show. If you were going to go down that road, because it makes more sense to you or whatever, then don't use a modal - those are specifically for displaying a modal screen over the currently displayed screen - just use a view like you mentioned.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: "How you are using it" is not quite an answer. Our app have over 30 different modals, so obviously we have conditionals around them. It doesn't make sense to render 30 hidden ones. It's React, conditional rendering must work. We have one big wrapper component to handle it all in once place (think a small router for modals). The conditional will choose which one to render (starting with visible=false, to let the modal render first, then using useEffect to set it to visible)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create useState to re-render your screen when you achieve the requirement to open the modal. For example:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Modal} from 'react-native'

const App = () => {
   const [state, setState] = useState(false)
   return(
      <Modal 
         style={styles.centeredView}
         animationType="slide"
         transparent={true}
         visible={state}
    />
  )
}
```

When you use `setState(true)` the Modal will open, `setState(false)` the Modal will close, so you need you to use `setState(true)` when the conditions to open the Modal was achieved

Comment: I have also tried this but whenever I change the state it has the same behaviour, Removes the existing view but the modal does not appear.

Comment: But does the modal is not appearing because you are defining it as transparent with ‘transparent=true’?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get this working but still don't fully understand why. I wrapped the modal in a view and then added a height to view and only then and with the height added does it work. If I remove the styles from the View it goes back to not working.

```
const OrderLineItem = ({item, finishEditingInQty}) => {

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    setSelected(item.selected)
})

if(selected){
    console.log("Item selected")
    return (
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
        <Modal
            style={styles.centeredView}
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={selected}
        >
            <View style={styles.modalLineItemContainer}>
                <View style={styles.modalLineItem}>
                    <Text>SELECTED</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.modalLineItem}>
                    <Text>{item.sageStockInfo.Barcode}</Text>
                </View>
                <Pressable
                    onPress={() => {
                        finishEditingInQty(item.LineID)
                    }}
                    style={({ pressed }) => [
                        {
                            backgroundColor: pressed
                            ? 'rgb(210, 230, 255)'
                            : 'white'
                        },
                        styles.orderListItem
                ]}>
                    <Text>Done</Text>
                </Pressable>
            </View>
        </Modal>
        </View>
    )
} else {
    return (
        <View style={styles.lineItemContainer}>
            <View style={styles.lineItem}>
                <Text style={styles.lineItemText}>{item.ProductCode} - {item.ProductDescription}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.lineItem}>
                <Text style={styles.lineItemText}>Outstanding: {item.Quantity}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.lineItemText}>In Qty: {item.inQty}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.lineItem}>
                <Text style={styles.lineItemText}>Warehouse: {item.Warehouse}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.lineItem}>
                <Text style={styles.lineItemText}>{item.sageStockInfo.Barcode}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
lineItemContainer: {
borderWidth: 3,
borderColor: "blue"

```
},
lineItem: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
},
lineItemText: {
    fontSize: 22
},
modalContainer: {
    height: 5

},
centeredView: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1
},
modalLineItemContainer: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: "red"
}
```

})

export default OrderLineItem;

Comment: I believe my answer clears up why you had to do what you did, as well as why you shouldn't do this the way you did.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I ended up just taking the selected item to a seperate component entirely and rendering it from the parent component anyway. Thanks